# phpMyAdmin Fatal Javascript Error Has Occurred

Tags: javascript, php, phpmyadmin

I am running phpMyAdmin version 4.4.4 on a CentOS Linux (2.6.32-504.12.2) server. I keep getting get a pink banner at the bottom of the PMA window stating: **A fatal JavaScript error has occurred. Would you like to send an error report?** If I click on Send Report, nothing happens. If I display the report details, this is what I see:

```
{
    "pma_version": "4.4.4",
    "browser_name": "FIREFOX",
    "browser_version": "37.0",
    "user_os": "Mac",
    "server_software": "Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips",
    "user_agent_string": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0",
    "locale": "en",
    "configuration_storage": "disabled",
    "php_version": "5.6.7",
    "exception_type": "js",
    "exception": {
        "mode": "stack",
        "name": "TypeError",
        "message": "field_id.match(...) is null",
        "stack": [
            {
                "func": "getFieldValidators",
                "args": "",
                "line": 302,
                "column": "16",
                "context": [
                    " * @return array of [function, parameters to be passed to function]",
                    " */",
                    "function getFieldValidators(field_id, onKeyUpOnly)",
                    "{",
                    "    // look for field bound validator",
                    "    var name = field_id.match(/[^-]+$/)[0];",
                    "    if (typeof validators._field[name] != 'undefined') {",
                    "        return [[validators._field[name], null]];",
                    "    }",
                    "",
                    "    // look for registered validators"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "validate_field",
                "args": "",
                "line": 418,
                "column": "21",
                "context": [
                    "{",
                    "    var args, result;",
                    "    var $field = $(field);",
                    "    var field_id = $field.attr('id');",
                    "    errors[field_id] = [];",
                    "    var functions = getFieldValidators(field_id, isKeyUp);",
                    "    for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {",
                    "        if (typeof functions[i][1] !== 'undefined' && functions[i][1] !== n//...",
                    "            args = functions[i][1].slice(0);",
                    "        } else {",
                    "            args = [];"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "?",
                "args": "",
                "line": 511,
                "column": "13",
                "context": [
                    "    var $check_page_refresh = $('#check_page_refresh');",
                    "    if ($check_page_refresh.length === 0 || $check_page_refresh.val() == '1') {",
                    "        // run all field validators",
                    "        var errors = {};",
                    "        for (var i = 0; i < $elements.length; i++) {",
                    "            validate_field($elements[i], false, errors);",
                    "        }",
                    "        // run all fieldset validators",
                    "        $('fieldset').each(function () {",
                    "            validate_fieldset(this, false, errors);",
                    "        });"
                ],
                "filename": "config.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "ErrorReport.wrap_function/new_func",
                "args": "",
                "line": 277,
                "column": "28",
                "context": [
                    "     */",
                    "    wrap_function: function (func) {",
                    "        if (!func.wrapped) {",
                    "            var new_func = function () {",
                    "                try {",
                    "                    return func.apply(this, arguments);",
                    "                } catch (x) {",
                    "                    TraceKit.report(x);",
                    "                }",
                    "            };",
                    "            new_func.wrapped = true;"
                ],
                "filename": "error_report.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "m.event.dispatch",
                "args": "",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "8384",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "$event.dispatch",
                "args": "",
                "line": 374,
                "column": "9",
                "context": [
                    "$event.dispatch = function( event ){",
                    "\tif ( $.data( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type ) - new Date().getTime() > 0 ){",
                    "\t\t$.removeData( this, \"suppress.\"+ event.type );",
                    "\t\treturn;",
                    "\t}",
                    "\treturn $dispatch.apply( this, arguments );",
                    "};",
                    "",
                    "// event fix hooks for touch events...",
                    "var touchHooks = ",
                    "$event.fixHooks.touchstart = "
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "m.event.add/r.handle",
                "args": "",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "5122",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "m.event.trigger",
                "args": "",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "7535",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": ".trigger/<",
                "args": "",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "15396",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": ".each",
                "args": "",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "2971",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "m.prototype.each",
                "args": "",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "833",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": ".trigger",
                "args": "",
                "line": 3,
                "column": "15375",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {",
                    "/*"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "AJAX.fireOnload",
                "args": "",
                "line": 109,
                "column": "9",
                "context": [
                    "     *",
                    "     * @return void",
                    "     */",
                    "    fireOnload: function (file) {",
                    "        var eventName = 'onload_' + AJAX.hash(file);",
                    "        $(document).trigger(eventName);",
                    "        if (this._debug) {",
                    "            console.log(",
                    "                // no need to translate",
                    "                \"Fired event \" + eventName + \" for file \" + file",
                    "            );"
                ],
                "filename": "ajax.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "?",
                "args": "",
                "line": "4",
                "column": "632",
                "uri": "sql.php?target=",
                "scriptname": "sql.php"
            },
            {
                "func": "m.Callbacks/j",
                "args": "",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "27239",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "m.Callbacks/k.fireWith",
                "args": "",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "28057",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": ".ready",
                "args": "",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "29889",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            },
            {
                "func": "J",
                "args": "",
                "line": 2,
                "column": "30255",
                "context": [
                    "/*! jQuery v1.11.1 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/li//...",
                    "!function(a,b){\"object\"==typeof module&&\"object\"==typeof module.exports?mod//...",
                    "if(k&&j[k]&&(e||j[k].data)||void 0!==d||\"string\"!=typeof b)return k||(k=i?a//...",
                    "},cur:function(){var a=Zb.propHooks[this.prop];return a&&a.get?a.get(this)://...",
                    ";",
                    "",
                    "function sprintf() {"
                ],
                "filename": "jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"
            }
        ],
        "useragent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:37.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/37.0",
        "incomplete": "false",
        "uri": "sql.php?target="
    },
    "script_name": "sql.php",
    "microhistory": {
        "current_index": "0"
    }
}
```

I've tried running phpMyAdmin in latest versions of Safari, Chrome and Firefox on a Mac (OS X Yosemite) and get the same fatal error in all three browsers. Anyone know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Is there a specific action you can take to trigger this error? Does it happen when you first load phpMyAdmin or after a period of use?

Comment: This error appears right after logging in. The problem seems to have been solved for some odd reason when I set up phpMyAdmin on a domain rather than an IP address. Now the errors are no longer showing. Strange!

Answer (score 1):

I also had error message like this- ("A fatal JavaScript error has occurred. Would you like to send an error report?") in Chrome browser. I tried 'localhost/phpmyadmin' in the incognito tab of the same browser, it worked well. This is a problem with Google Chrome last update. This problem occurs in other jQuery and other codes.
Alternatively, just disable PageXray extension in Chrome browser and try once. Good luck!!!

Comment: just disable PageXray extension !? 
I feel so stupid. Love you, Deepak! 
You saved my day. Thank you !